# PostCSS preset env alpha hex colors not working with sass variables

Tags: sass, postcss

While using postcss-preset-env I get the following results:

```
$black: #000000; 
color: #{$black}de;
```

In development it will return the expected:

```
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87059);
```

But in production:

```
color: #000de;
```

In `package.json` I have the following scripts:

```
"dev": "cross-env webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --mode=development -w --hot",
"prod": "cross-env webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode=production -p"
```

And in `webpack.config.js`

```
{
    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
    exclude: ['/node_modules', './dist', '/src/js', '/docs'],
    use: [
        MiniCSSExtractPlugin.loader,
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                minimize: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                syntax: postCssScss,
                plugins: () => [
                    autoprefixer,
                    postCssPresetEnv({
                        stage: 0,
                        features: {
                            'color-mod-function': true,
                            'alpha-hex-colors': true
                        }
                    }),
                ],
            },
        },
        {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to use it without the `features` part that didn't work. Also tried to require the `color-mod-function` and `alpha-hex-colors` as seperate package after the `autoprefixer` which also didn't work.

So how can I get the same output from development in production?

Have already made an [issue](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-color-hex-alpha/issues/9) for it but maybe someone knows a way to solve this.